# Flot on Rails placeholder is undefined

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, flot

i'm using Flot jquery and i dont know why i'm having this error

```
TypeError: placeholder.css(...) is undefined    

jquery...?body=1 (line 741)

size: Math.round(0.8 * (+placeholder.css("font-size").replace("px", "") || 13))
```

Probably the issue comes cause i'm using bootstrap but i dont know how to fix this 
my simple css

```
#flotchart { width: 900px; height: 400px; position: relative; padding: 0; }
```

And the graph is a generic simple flot chart
Thanks for any help

Comment: `placeholder` is not defined.

Comment: I did copy and paste from firebug he say `is undefined`

Comment: Please show us the code where you are defining and setting the placeholder variable.

Answer (score 1):

this is the simple explanation. i have js on document ready like this

```
 $.plot("#placeholder2"
 $.plot("#placeholder5"
```

but my html only have

```
<div id="placeholder5"
```

and thats return error *placeholder.css is undefined*

what i do to fix that is really simple just add condition if that id is exists

```
if($("#placeholder2").length > 0)
   $.plot("#placeholder2"
```